# How to show half star rating using cosmos rating controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using cosmos rating controller to implement rating functionality in my IOS app.I have successfully saved ratings on database(using API), but i got stuck with a problem that when i am fetching rating value from database and setting it to cosmos view(cosmosview.rating = value) it's not showing half rating star or star with decimal values like 3.75,3.5.All it's showing is full star i.e for 3.5 rating, it is showing 4 star.Please tell me what is the problem here. The github link is given below:
https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the fill mode to be used. By default it is `.Full`, but you want `.Precise`:

```
cosmosView.settings.fillMode = .Full
```

Comment: @Wain...I have already tried this.It's not working, giving an error!!

Comment: So give details of that in the question. Show the code and the error

Comment: It's working now (cosmosView.settings.fillMode = .Precise)...Fault was from my side...Thanks @Wain